# spinLock locks up the system

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, vxworks

I am attempting to use `spinlockIsr_t`in vxWorks 6.7 but if I try to use it with multiple tasks the system freezes. Are you allowed to use multiple tasks that attempt to acquire the same spin lock? If not then whats the point of it in the first place? The following code works with 1 or 2 tasks but once the number of tasks is increased to 3 system freezes before being able to finish printing first line on console.

```
spinlockIsr_t mySpinLock; 
int sharedResource;
void vx_test_mtx_spin_lock(void)
{
    const int kNumTask = 3;
    const int kTaskPriority = 50;
    const int kTaskStackSize = 10000;
    int i = 0;
    sharedResource = 0;
    char procName[40];
                                                printf("Number of tasks : %d\n", kNumTask);
                                                printf("SPIN_LOCK_ISR_INIT() [main task]\n");
    SPIN_LOCK_ISR_INIT (&mySpinLock, 0);        printf("SPIN_LOCK_ISR_TAKE() [main task] \n");
    SPIN_LOCK_ISR_TAKE (&mySpinLock);
    for (i = 0; i < kNumTask; i++){
        sprintf(procName, "%s%d", "myTask", i); printf("taskSpawn() [main task]\n");
        taskSpawn((char*)procName,
                kTaskPriority,
                0,
                kTaskStackSize,
                (FUNCPTR)vx_spin_lock_unlock,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
                );
    }                                           printf("SPIN_LOCK_ISR_GIVE() [main task]");
    SPIN_LOCK_ISR_GIVE (&mySpinLock); 

}

void vx_spin_lock_unlock(void)
{
                                                printf("SPIN_LOCK_ISR_TAKE() [spawned task] \n");
    SPIN_LOCK_ISR_TAKE (&mySpinLock);
    /* ... Access the share resource here */    printf("SPIN_LOCK_ISR_GIVE() [spawned task] \n");
    SPIN_LOCK_ISR_GIVE (&mySpinLock);       
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you have a higher-priority task spinning on the spinlock while a lower-priority task already holds the lock. The lower-priority task will never be able to run, and therefore the lock is never unlocked, and deadlock occurs. Spinlocks should basically never be used in realtime systems. If they are used, you must ensure that all threads that could spin on the lock have the same priority.

Comment: +1 - I have seen spinlocks bring down a whole cluster - 7 boxes stuck, one box looping :((

Comment: Spinlock disasters are usually described as 'livelock':(

Comment: OK, good to know. Sorry I have no formal education in concurrency so I don't always know the right terms.

Comment: The main task that initially takes the Spin Lock has the highest priority of 1 and the spawned tasks have priority of 50 so shouldn't the main task be allowed to release the lock and allow the other spawned tasks to finish their execution.

Comment: Does the main task every attempt to reacquire the spinlock after releasing it the first time?

Comment: printf must have its own lock to prevent output buffer corruption - maybe that's a spinlock as well :((

Comment: I doubt it. Using spinlocks for inside stdio on an implementation intended for realtime systems would be show-stoppingly bad.

Comment: @R.. - oh yes, missed the 'VxWorks' tag :(

Answer (score 1):

This is really a mis-application of the spinLocks.
In most cases, you should simply use a mutex semaphore instead of the spinLock.

SpinLocks are intended to have a very short critical section.
Doing string and I/O (i.e. printf) operations is **not** short.
Same with doing a taskSpawn.

In fact, doing any system call while holding a spin lock is a huge red flag.

Comment: +1, side effects start at a waste of a CPU core and memory bandwidth and get worse from there :(

Comment: The reason I am trying to spawn a task while holding a spin lock is to test a wrapper around spin locks.

Answer (score 0):

How many cores do you have in that system? Is there anything to preempts spinning tasks?
Since all your tasks spin on a lock, once you pegged all you cores - game's over.

Comment: 2 cores. No there is nothing that preempts the tasks. The main task has priority of 1 while the spawned tasks have priority of 50 so I was assuming the main task will be scheduled and give the spin lock even though the spawned tasks are spinning on the lock.